# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+a}{1-3x}=a$, $a>0$, by $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

We have
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{x+a}{1-3x} - a \right| &= \left| \frac{x+a-a+3ax}{1-3x} \right| \\[1em]
&= \left| \frac{x(1+3a)}{1-3x}\right|\\[1em] 
&=  \frac{|x|(1+3a)}{|1-3x|} <\epsilon.
\end{align}
By stating  that $|x|<\delta$, we can proceed by
\begin{align}
 |x| <\frac{\epsilon|1-3x|}{1+3a}.
\end{align}
By restricting $-1/3<x<1/3$ we have that for such $x$ and for  any  $\epsilon$, the corresponding $\delta$ is $\min\{1, 2\epsilon/(1+3a) \}$.

Is this right?

Comment: How do you know that $\delta<1/3$? and your first inequality does not make sense to me, as $a>0$.

Comment: so? Does it imply $\delta<1/3$??

Comment: You are right. I've slightly edited the answer...

Comment: Note that you can center math using the `$$` construction (no need to use the `align` environment unless you have something like in my answer where you need things to be stretched vertically),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those cases where starting off with $\delta=1$ is not optimal. If you let $\delta=\frac{1}{6}$, then note that
\begin{align}
|x|<\frac{1}{6}&\Longleftrightarrow -\frac{1}{6}<x<\frac{1}{6}\\[1em]
&\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{6}>-x>-\frac{1}{6}\\[1em]
&\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}>-3x>-\frac{1}{2}\\[1em]
&\Longleftrightarrow \frac{3}{2}>1-3x>\frac{1}{2}\\[1em]
&\Longleftrightarrow \frac{2}{3}<\frac{1}{1-3x}<2\\[1em]
&\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1+3a}{1-3x}<2+3a.
\end{align}
Thus, we should choose $\delta=\min\left\{\frac{1}{6},\frac{\epsilon}{2+3a}\right\}$. To see that this choice of $\delta$ works, consider the following:

Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\min\left\{\frac{1}{6},\frac{\epsilon}{2+3a}\right\}$. If $|x|<\frac{1}{6}$, then $\left|\frac{1+3a}{1-3x}\right|<2+3a$. Also, $|x|<\frac{\epsilon}{2+3a}$. Hence,
$$\left|\frac{x+a}{1-3x}-a\right|=|x|\left|\frac{1+3a}{1-3x}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2+3a}\cdot(2+3a)=\epsilon,
$$
as desired.

Comment: In the last inequality shouldn't it $2+6a$?

Comment: I just added some parens I forgot by accident. Does that help? If that isn't what you saw, then you *do* need to have the "$2+3a$" term so that you are left only with $\epsilon$, as desired.

Comment: $\delta$ is $\min\{...\}$, right?

Comment: Yes! Nice spot--without that condition, the argument is worthless. Also, I had "If $|x|>\frac{1}{6}$" a moment ago where I clearly meant "If $|x|<\frac{1}{6}$." It should be corrected now.

Comment: Thanks. Choosing other value (larger) than $1/6$ will just lead to less elegant manipulations, right?

Comment: Perhaps. It really comes down to convenience and taste, honestly (whatever works). For example, I actually started fiddling around with this problem where I let $\delta=1$ at first, but that did not really help matters. Thus, I chose another $\delta$-value or two before landing on $\delta=\frac{1}{6}$, which worked out just fine. Sometimes you simply have to experiment.

Comment: I see. Many thanks! :-)

Comment: Sure thing! Good luck with the rest of your problems. `:-)`